# Error in seq_len(nrow(pts)) argument must be coercible to non-negative integer in vegan

Tags: r, vegan

I tried to make plot of biplot of CCA to show environmental variables in ordination space. 
I had the following code:
`CCA <- cca(spec ~., env)`
`plot(CCA, dis="sp", type="n")`
`text(CCA, dis="cn", col="blue")` 
It doesn't matter whether I run RDA or CCA or in space of sites `dis="sites"`or species I receive the same error. 
 (however, in previous version of vegan 2.5-6 it worked properly): 
`Error in seq_len(nrow(pts)) :  argument must be coercible to non-negative integer  In addition: Warning message: In seq_len(nrow(pts)) : first element used of 'length.out' argument`

Comment: Can you show a reproducible example with `dput`.  I tried the example in `?cca` and it is working fine (version is 2.5.7 - current CRAN version)

Comment: Yes, example in vegan works fine. I checked too. Here is link to two text.files spec and env. Let me know if you get it. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/15Sb3_TEpbcHONWBH24jCXhRvU34S9hnC?usp=sharing

Comment: Are you getting the error only with `text`

Comment: Yes, only with `text` and `dis='cn'`

Comment: I am not sure whether it needs to change the class from numeric to factor or not `env[] <- lapply(env, factor)` and then your code works

Comment: No, it works but differently. It shows all values of variables (as factors) but arrows should be shown.

Comment: I tried to extract scores from model but for `$centroids` I get `[1] NA` I gave you small dataset. Originally I worked on much larger. Previous version 2.5.6 works fine.

Comment: can you raise an issue in their github page

Comment: Besides, when I run `plot(CCA)` then environmental variables are shown as arrows. That's strange.

Comment: The reason I changed to factor is that in their examples showed in `plot.cca` one of the datasets have ordered factors

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce this error if I ask to plot `"cn"` scores, and there are no `"cn"` scores. The function does not correctly recognize that it got nothing to plot and runs into error you reported.

The `"cn"` scores are only calculated for factor variables, and if you do not have any factors, you have no centroids (`"cn"`). That's why the function worked when akrun changed your variables into factors.

I have now fixed this in github, and the  fixed `text.cca` should behave similarly as in vegan 2.5-6. This will be in the next release (but we have no current plans of release). Meanwhile you can get the github version, or circumvent the problem by not using `display="cn"` when there are no `"cn"` scores: then you should just call `text(..., display="bp")`. Calling `scores(..., display = "cn")` will show you if you have any `"cn"` scores. I admit this is cumbersome, but the fix is there.

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed, `text(..., display="bp")` works perfectly. So, for me, problem is fixed. I understood what acrun had did and what were the consequences but results were not satisfactory. I wanted to have numeric variables and not to change them into factors.